# pear install bbcode to specific php version on LTS 16.4

Tags: 16.04, php

To install php pecl's bbcode extension I know I need to use:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
pecl install bbcode
```

But... I'm on Ubuntu LTS 16.04 which installed php7.0 by default. I've installed 5.6 to run along side as this is version I need for now.

However whenever I install something with pecl it automatically installs it to 7.0. How can I force pecl to install to version 5.6? Or is there a manual method of copying the relevant files to 5.6 from 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

it should update the php version for the cli to be the 5.6 and with that make the system to use that php version. Not sure if it would work for pecl though.